# Getting error in handler using Nservicebus version 6.2.0 with rabitMQ transport

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, nservicebus6

I'm using Nservicebus version 6.2.0 with rabitMQ transport (NServiceBus.RabbitMQ version 5.0.0). 
I received an error on in the service bus in my handler

ERROR NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutor Moving message '34894416-ea8a-4d5a-ae41-a95e00f51a35' to the error queue 'error' because processing failed due to an exception:
NServiceBus.MessageDeserializationException: An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from transport message 34894416-ea8a-4d5a-ae41-a95e00f51a35 ---> NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[Unavailable#]-failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationException(String message) in c:\Source control\Git\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:line 483
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected() in c:\Source control\Git\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:line 477
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing) in c:\Source control\Git\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:line 465
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Write() in c:\Source control\Git\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Collection\AbstractPersistentCollection.cs:line 362
   at NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag.Add(Object value) in c:\Source control\Git\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Collection\PersistentBag.cs:line 379
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.Extract(IncomingMessage physicalMessage) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.cs:line 115
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.ExtractWithExceptionHandling(IncomingMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.cs:line 44
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.ExtractWithExceptionHandling(IncomingMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.cs:line 48
   at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.InvokeAuditPipelineBehavior.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\InvokeAuditPipelineBehavior.cs:line 18
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.ReceivePerformanceDiagnosticsBehavior.d__2.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Performance\Statistics\ReceivePerformanceDiagnosticsBehavior.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.MutateIncomingTransportMessageBehavior.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutators\MutateTransportMessage\MutateIncomingTransportMessageBehavior.cs:line 43
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Performance\Statistics\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line 27
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus.TransactionScopeSuppressBehavior.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\2f57832e2eee436e\src\Transport\Receiving\TransactionScopeSuppressBehavior.cs:line 23
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.TransportReceiveToPhysicalMessageProcessingConnector.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\TransportReceiveToPhysicalMessageProcessingConnector.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.MainPipelineExecutor.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\MainPipelineExecutor.cs:line 32
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ.MessagePump.d__29.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\ef98ad7376e3379a\src\NServiceBus.RabbitMQ\Receiving\MessagePump.cs:line 249

Comment: Looks like a serialisation exception... MessageDeserializationException
Are you using the same seriliser on all endpoints?
Do you have the correct Message assembly referenced in your handling endpoint?
Do you have any Assembly scanning restrictions?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same serializer on all endpoints. I Exclude some DLLs and types like postsharp.dll

Comment: It might be you need to include the dlls that are nor core packages of NServuiceBus... https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning